# how to get last or next Id

Tags: php, my-model-jami

Using Jamie Rumbelow's My_Model and mySQL. I am not able to find, how to get a last inserted Id in a particular table. For example,

```
Table_A

--------+
id      |
--------+
1       |
--------+
2       |
--------+
```

I am try below code but it returning `int(0)`

```
  $id = $this->Model_teacher->_database->insert_id();
```

Comment: Please clarify what framework or library you are using, your code to insert in the first place, what made you decide to try `$this->Model_teacher->_database->insert_id()`. Right now it is unclear how anyone can help you.

Comment: I am using PHP CodeIgniter and using Jamie Rumbelow's My_Model. I want to get last Id of table (for example teacherId)... I want to manipulate is Id for other column then I want to trigger actual insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the library you are using.. https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model/blob/master/core/MY_Model.php

```
public function insert($data, $skip_validation = FALSE)
    {
        if ($skip_validation === FALSE)
        {
            $data = $this->validate($data);
        }
        if ($data !== FALSE)
        {
            $data = $this->trigger('before_create', $data);
            $this->_database->insert($this->_table, $data);
            $insert_id = $this->_database->insert_id();
            $this->trigger('after_create', $insert_id);
            return $insert_id;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

When an insert is successful, it returns `$insert_id;`

```
$id = $this->Model_teacher->insert(...);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get last inserted Id. so I can do +1 and prepare value for some other column and then prepare final insert data. Otherwise, I need to do insert first and then update same inserted record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Returns the ID of the last inserted row

```
$con -> lastInsertId();
```

Comment: a little description always much better with the code.

Comment: @urfusion : `lastInsertId` = `last + Insert + Id`
Isn't clear ?

Comment: pretty much clear. I am talking about the standard which should be used.